# Plotly Warning message: 'scatter' objects don't have these attributes:

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to add a moving average to a chart and the code is working fine, but I am getting a warning, what am I doing wrong?
I just started learning plotly, so I don't always understand what I'm doing

here is my code

```
library(magrittr)
library(xts)
len <- 30000
times <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00"), length = len, by = "sec")
prices <- cumsum(rnorm(len))


p <- prices %>%
      as.xts(order.by = times) %>% 
      to.minutes5()

dat <- cbind.data.frame(index(p) , coredata(p))
colnames(dat) <- c("date","open","high","low","close")

dat$sma10 <- TTR::SMA(dat$close,10)



library(plotly)
  plot_ly(dat, x = ~date, type="candlestick",
          open = ~open, close = ~close,
          high = ~high, low = ~low) %>%
  add_lines(x = ~date, y = ~sma10, name = "sma10", line = list(color = 'blue')) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(visible = F)),
         yaxis = list(side = "right"))
```

message

```
Warning message:
'scatter' objects don't have these attributes: 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low'
Valid attributes include:
'cliponaxis', 'connectgaps', 'customdata', 'customdatasrc', 'dx', 'dy', 'error_x', 'error_y', 'fill', 'fillcolor', 'fillpattern', 'groupnorm', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverinfosrc', 'hoverlabel', 'hoveron', 'hovertemplate', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'hovertext', 'hovertextsrc', 'ids', 'idssrc', 'legendgroup', 'legendgrouptitle', 'legendrank', 'line', 'marker', 'meta', 'metasrc', 'mode', 'name', 'opacity', 'orientation', 'selected', 'selectedpoints', 'showlegend', 'stackgaps', 'stackgroup', 'stream', 'text', 'textfont', 'textposition', 'textpositionsrc', 'textsrc', 'texttemplate', 'texttemplatesrc', 'transforms', 'type', 'uid', 'uirevision', 'unselected', 'visible', 'x', 'x0', 'xaxis', 'xcalendar', 'xhoverformat', 'xperiod', 'xperiod0', 'xperiodalignment', 'xsrc', 'y', 'y0', 'yaxis', 'ycalendar', 'yhoverformat', 'yperiod', 'yperiod0', 'yperiodalignment', 'ysrc', 'key', 'set', 'frame', 'transforms', ' [... truncated]
```

my session

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default


time zone: Europe/Kiev
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] magrittr_2.0.3    mt5R_0.1.5        htmlwidgets_1.6.2 plotly_4.10.1     ggplot2_3.4.2    
 [6] quantmod_0.4.22   TTR_0.24.3        xts_0.13.1        zoo_1.8-12        shiny_1.7.4
```

Comment: It's nothing to worry about. It comes from adding `add_lines`. Since the line graph is a scatter graph in Plotly, it checks the conceptual requirements against the candlestick, as well. Of course, the candlestick chart doesn't have the same arguments. If you reverse the trace order (lines first, then the candlestick) you'll get a slightly different warning--what elements of a line graph are not in a candlestick graph.